# Does QuickFix engine provide recovery by default

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I am using QuickFix engine based Initiator application. Will that application handle recovery by default or I need to provide MessageStoreFactory? If needed then I will use "FileStoreFactory".

Also I assume default "MessageStoreFactory" and "LogFactory" must be doing it synchronously and that will affect the latency? Is my assumption correct?